# Thread refuses to quit

Tags: qt

Source: https://mega.co.nz/#!xUMiSRYC!Y8Sxz2fEFb6yEIrnKiGx9n2zeK4YTUwUrCByaAkcOPI

I'm experiencing a problem with QThread::currentThread()->quit();

If you open up my myobject.cpp and go to line 13, the quit() call is supposed to exit. But it seems the quit() call isn't working and it just skips it. Can't see the problem. :(

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    QObject::connect(&a, SIGNAL(aboutToQuit()),
                     &w, SLOT(cleanUp()));

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "myobject.h"
#include <QMessageBox>

MyObject* cObject;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setFixedSize(this->size());

    cThread = new QThread(this);
    cObject = new MyObject();
    cObject->moveToThread(cThread);

    QObject::connect(ui->pushButton_2, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this, SLOT(close()));

    QObject::connect(cThread, SIGNAL(started()),
                     cObject, SLOT(doWork()));

    QObject::connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this, SLOT(runThreadSlot()));

    QObject::connect(cThread, SIGNAL(finished()),
                     cThread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    QObject::connect(cThread, SIGNAL(finished()),
                     cObject, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    QObject::connect(cObject, SIGNAL(setStatusBarSignal(QString)),
                     this, SLOT(setStatusBarSlot(QString)));

    ui->lineEdit->setValidator(new QIntValidator(this));
    ui->lineEdit->setFocus(Qt::OtherFocusReason);
    ui->statusBar->showMessage("Waiting for input...");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::runThreadSlot()
{
    cThread->start();
    // I've trimmed some code here.
}

void MainWindow::setStatusBarSlot(QString text)
{
    ui->statusBar->showMessage(text);
}

void MainWindow::cleanUp()
{
    qDebug() << "Cleaning up!";
    cObject->stage = 0;
    cThread->wait();
}
```

myobject.cpp:

```
#include "myobject.h"
#include <QPixmap>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

MyObject::MyObject(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

void MyObject::doWork()
{
    QThread::currentThread()->quit(); // It doesn't stop here. This is my issue.
    // I've trimmed the code here.
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void runThreadSlot();
    void setStatusBarSlot(QString);
    void cleanUp();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QThread* cThread;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

myobject.h:

```
#ifndef MYOBJECT_H
#define MYOBJECT_H

#include <QtCore>

class MyObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyObject(QObject *parent = 0);
    QFile path;
    qint32 waitSecs;
    int stage;

signals:
    void setStatusBarSignal(QString);

public slots:
    void doWork();

};

#endif // MYOBJECT_H
```

Comment: you should post your code, not provide a link to download it

Comment: @ashley: It requires files though for resources.

Comment: You should post the _relevant_ part of your code here, or better yet an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). No-one here is going to go through that blind link and download from that fishy source.

Comment: Maybe I should just start a new project, try to replicate this issue, and repost this question?

Comment: Yes, trying to isolate the issue and posting a _minimal_ piece of code that reproduces it is exactly what you should be doing. Edit your question so that includes only that minimal test-case once you manage that.

Answer (score 1):

`QThread::quit()` is asynchronous. You shoul add `QThread::currentThread()->wait()` right after quit.